# Trying to find and the most frequently used word in a list and its frequency .But it looks like there might be a overlooked logical error

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, logic, nested-loops

I have a method thats supposed to be returning the most used word in a 1D array.
The testing text: There is a very fat cat, the fat is something else. fat fat fat fat. Come on fat is the most used word.
It should be returning - fat 7
But returns There 1  instead

Ive tried moving the "track>maxFrequency" if statement outside of the inner for loop, but it returns the same thing. Ive also taken that if statment out of the one its nested in. Getting some tunnel vision

```
public String findFrequentWord() {
  String finalP = "";
  int maxFrequency = 0; // most used word count
  int track= 0; //keeping count of how many times a word appears
  for(int start = 0; start<textList.size();start++){ // picks 1 word at a time
    for(int next = 0; next<textList.size();next++){ // looks for that word in the entire array before moving to the next word in the list
      if(textList.get(start)==textList.get(next)){ //when the currently examined word shows up in the list
        track++;    // that words apperance count goes up
        if(track>maxFrequency){ // before going onto the next word we check if the words apperence is higher                  than the current max frquency
          maxFrequency = track; // if it is we update the new maxiumum
          finalP = textList.get(start); //we update the word displayed the most
          } //nested  if end
      } // if end
    } //inner (next) for loop ends
    track = 0; // reset tracking number for the next word
  } // outter loop ends
  return finalP + " " + maxFrequency; // display the most used word and how many times it showed up
}
```

Comment: Use `.equals`, not `==`, to compare `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the outer if statement, problem solved.

```
if((textList.get(start)).equals(textList.get(next))){
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of == in the first outer if try use .equals and your problem is solved.

A:s I have mentioned below:

```
if((textList.get(start)).equals(textList.get(next)))
```